# How to register spring MVC application to spring boot admin

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I have spring MVC web application. I have used spring boot actuator in it by adding dependancies as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

In my configuration file, I have imported classes as below.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.test.*"})
@Import({EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class,
ManagementServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class, EndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class,PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:appconfig.properties")
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

Now when I hit url "http://localhost:8080/health", I am getting response

```
{"status":"UP","diskSpace":{"status":"UP","total":493767094272,"free":417100754944,"threshold":10485760}}
```

So, this works perfect. Now my question is how to register this spring MVC web application to spring-boot-admin server.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: And what does [documentation](http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.1/#getting-started) say?

Comment: I did that part, followed the doc and apply it in the application, but it doesn't show any error and not registered to admin server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use Spring Boots autoconfiguration (`@EnableAutoConfiguration`), have a look at the `SpringBootAdminClientAutoConfiguration` form the spring-boot-admin-starter-client library there are all components configured used for registering at the admin server.

Primarily the `ApplicationRegistrator` and some taskScheduler for issuing the frequent registration.

If you don't want to use the client-lib at all you could also register via a simple http post request to the admin-server's `/api/applications` endpoint.

```
$ curl -H"Content-Type: application/json" --data '{ "serviecUrl":"http://localhost:8080/", "healthUrl":"http://localhost:8080/health", "managementUrl":"http://localhost:8080/","name":"my-app"}' http://<adminserver-host>:<port>/api/applications
```

Comment: does it work for you in spring mvc project? Can you show how you did it?@Harshil